# Non-negative covariance

Tags: statistics

I'm reading [this paper](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/picasso/mats/PCA-Tutorial-Intuition_jp.pdf) and on page 5, it states that the covariance between two elements is positive ($\sigma_{AB} \geq 0$).  Why is this true? If $<a_ib_i>$ is just the average over the dot product, can't that be negative?

Comment: Certainly covariance *in general* can be negative.  I am working with a very poor screen, cannot find an assertion on page 5 that in this case it is non-negative.

Comment: I agree with André Nicolas that there seems to be no assertion that the covariance is nonnegative. But notice that the paper uses the  **dreadful** choice of notation $\sigma_{AB}^2$ for the _covariance_ (presumably by analogy with $\sigma_A^2$ for the variance) which would seem to imply that the covariance is always nonnegative (the paper itself does not make this inference).

Comment: How does $\sigma^2_{AB} \geq 0$ make $\sigma_{AB}$ nonnegative? Or better yet, what is $\sigma_{AB}$? I think I'm just getting confused over the notation...

Comment: Also, the author later goes on to say "By definition covariances must be non-negative, thus the minimal covariance is zero"

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial on Principal Component Analysis written by Shlens is great! I learned a lot from it. However, those descriptions about covariance $\sigma^2_{AB} \geq 0$, including line 13 on the left side and line 28 on the right side of page 5, were in the previous version 2 of the paper (2005) and were misunderstandingly incorrect. The covariance of $A$ and $B$ equals to $\sigma^2_{AB} = \rho \sigma_A \sigma_B$, where $\rho$ is the correlation coefficient of $A$ and $B$ with $-1 \le \rho \le 1$, $\sigma^2_A$ and $\sigma^2_B$ is the variance of $A$ and $B$, respectively. From the above we know that covariance could be negative.

The above incorrect descriptions were revised on the latest version of the paper; please refer to Shlens's [revised paper on 2014](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.1100).